# Plot multiple line segments using three columns and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to plot multiple line segments from three columns of data?

| LM | LR | DB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 372 | 387 | 93 |
| 387 | 396 | 89 |
| 351 | 454 | 370 |

This is an example of the data I have with LM being length at original marking, LR being length and Recapture and DB being days between marking and recapture.

Is there a way using ggplot2 to plot each row as a line segment with Length (the first two columns) being the y axis and days being the x axis?

Comment: So in the plot you want three vertical line segments at position `DB`?

Comment: `geom_segment()` ?

Comment: I'm interested in two points, the first being LM the second being LR (y axis) and the line segment in between being the distance DB (x axis) between the two. With LM being at the beginning of the segment and LR at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use this code:

```
df <- data.frame(LM = c(372, 387, 351),
                 LR = c(387, 396, 454),
                 DB = c(93, 89, 370))

df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = DB, y = LM)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = DB, y = LR)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = DB, y = LM, xend = DB, yend = LR))
```

Output plot:

[image]